# When to use IN OR AND in a sub-query? (SQL oracle data base hr schema )

Tags: sql, oracle

I had to do this sub-query
EXP: Write a query to display the employee number, name (first name and last name), and salary for all employees who earn more than the average salary and who work in a department with an employee with a J in their name.

AND the code for the sub query is the following

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name ,e. salary  
FROM employees e 
WHERE e.salary >  (SELECT AVG (e.salary)   FROM employees e ) 
AND  e.department_id IN  ( SELECT e.department_id   FROM employees  e  WHERE e.first_name LIKE '%J%');
```

Why I can't use this code when I have 'IN' instead of AND

```
select e.employee_id,e.first_name ,e.salary from employees e
where e.salary > (select avg(e.salary) from employees e where e.department_id in
(select e.department_id from employees e where e.first_name like '%J%'));
```

I know the second code is wrong, but why?

Comment: Whilst reusing aliases from the outer query inside subqueries is legal, I'd usually recommend against it. Even if either piece of code above is correct, it makes it difficult to quickly *read and understand* the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.first_name ,e. salary  
FROM employees e
```

We'll ignore the above, other than to say we're looking for employees

```
WHERE e.salary >  (SELECT AVG (e.salary)   FROM employees e )
```

Where that employee's salary is greater than the average salary for all employees

```
AND e.department_id IN (
  SELECT e.department_id FROM employees e WHERE e.first_name LIKE '%J%');
```

And where that employee is in a department where at least one employee's first name contains a `J`.

Next!

---

```
select e.employee_id,e.first_name ,e.salary from employees e
```

We'll ignore the above, other than to say we're looking for employees

```
where e.salary > (select avg(e.salary) from employees e
```

Where that employee's salary is greater than the average salary

```
where e.department_id in
(select e.department_id from employees e where e.first_name like '%J%'));
```

for employees in a department where at least one employee's first name contains a `J`.

---

The two are answering different questions:

- Look for employees where that employee's salary is greater than the average salary for all employees and where that employee is in a department where at least one employee's first name contains a `J`.

and:

- Look for employees where that employee's salary is greater than the average salary for employees in a department where at least one employee's first name contains a `J`.

And note that the difference is precisely on how the "in a department where at least one employee's first name contains a `J`" constraint is applied. In the first, it's applied as a constraint on the overall search for employees. In the second, it's applied as a constraint over which employee's we're computing an average salary for.

Given the wording of the spec, I'd say it's correct that the constraint should be applied to the overall search and not to the computation of the average salary, and so the first query is correct.

---

> Why I can't use this code when I have 'IN' instead of AND

That's not how I'd characterize the difference between the two queries. Note that they *both* use `IN`. The difference is in which query (or subquery) you're applying predicates to. The first adds an `AND` because we now have two predicates applied to the outer query and we need some kind of operator to combine those predicates (`AND` seems correct here versus the alternative of `OR`).

In the second you don't find yourself combining multiple predicates because you're applying predicates to different queries.

Comment: Thanks for answer , Wish you a nice day .

Answer (score 0):

The query asks us to find employees who have their salary > the average salary of **ALL** the employees and who work in a department with any employee with a J in their name.
So , in your code you've calculated the average salary only for employees who work in a department with any employee with a J in their name. In this case you need to use **AND**  because average salary of all the employees and the employees  who work in a department with any employee with a J in their name are independent of each other.